# Touchpad Options missing from System Settings

Tags: 14.04, drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a Razer Blade 14" running 14.04. When I start the computer rarely will the touchpad options appear in the settings. When they do, it works fine. More often than not, however, the settings are not present there and the two finger scrolling, disabling when typing, etc. do not work. I can't seem to find any pattern to when it works or doesn't, although it doesn't work much more often than it does. The touchpad still works in general. I can move it and click both with the physical buttons and tapping, its just the two finger scrolling, and other features that do not work (it also seems to mess with the sensitivity when they do not work as well).

Here's the output for xinput list, it's currently not working.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Blade                         id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And here's the /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1532 Product=011d Version=0111
N: Name="Razer Razer Blade"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.0/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1532 Product=011d Version=0111
N: Name="Razer Razer Blade"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.1/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=10001f
B: KEY=4837fff072ff32d bf54444600000000 1 30f908b17c007 ffff7bfad941dfff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=40
B: ABS=3fffff0100000000
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1532 Product=011d Version=0111
N: Name="Razer Razer Blade"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.2/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=1000000000007 ff9f207ac14057ff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1532 Product=011d Version=0111
N: Name="Razer Razer Blade"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input3
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5/3-5:1.3/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1bcf Product=2c11 Version=1215
N: Name="HD WebCam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-14/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-14/3-14:1.0/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/device:54/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:01/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10
```

UPDATE: I am able to get it to work correctly more consistently using the driver as described here : http://zhehou.blogspot.com/2014/07/razer-blade-14-touchpad-multitouch-in.html

It doesn't work after every reboot though. It seems to work more often when I run make install and depmod -a before rebooting. I couldn't get the fix in the link to work to allow it to work from a fresh startup, although it does seem to work more often from a reboot, although even then not always.

Comment: They "fixed" the random part. Now with kernel 3.17 and above touchpad simply doesn't work at all. I have the same laptop and am facing the same issue. Here you can upvote the bug on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1315360 and here is some activity on archlinux forum about patching kernel to make touchpad work: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173356 (kernel is shared among distros so Ubuntu would take advantage of that as well). It's unclear to me did they succeed or not.